# Copy data from a row to another row in Pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a (pandas) dataframe like this:

```
Index       A  ID   B  C
1           a   1   0  0
2           b   2   0  0
3           c   2   a  a
4           d   3   0  0
```

I want to copy the data of the third row to the second row, because their IDs are matching, but the data is not filled. However, I want to leave column 'A' intact. Looking for a result like this:

```
Index       A  ID   B  C
1           a   1   0  0
2           b   2   a  a
3           c   2   a  a
4           d   3   0  0
```

What would you suggest as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing `'0'` with `NaN` then `ffill()`+`bfill()` using `groupby()`+`apply()`:

```
df[['B','C']]=df[['B','C']].replace('0',float('NaN'))
df[['B','C']]=df.groupby('ID')[['B','C']].apply(lambda x:x.ffill().bfill()).fillna('0')
```

output of df:

```
 Index  A   ID  B   C
0   1   a   1   0   0
1   2   b   2   a   a
2   3   c   2   a   a
3   4   d   3   0   0
```

**Note:** you can also use `transform()` method in place of `apply()` method

Comment: Group by might be a good direction, didn't even consider it. I'm not familiar with the bfill() method though, need to look it up.

Comment: @MilanSzabo what is your expected output from this dataframe? `pd.DataFrame({'Index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: '5'},
 'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
 'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: '1'},
 'B': {0: 'b', 1: '0', 2: 'a', 3: '0', 4: '0'},
 'C': {0: 'b', 1: '0', 2: 'a', 3: '0', 4: '0'}})`

Comment: It's the following: pd.DataFrame({'Index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: '5'},  'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},  'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: '1'},  'B': {0: 'b', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: '0', 4: 'b'},  'C': {0: 'b', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: '0', 4: 'b'}})

Comment: @MilanSzabo updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: quite intriguing, thanks! i'll test it for sure.

Comment: @MilanSzabo but make sure that values inside the'ID' column are of same datatype

Comment: I have tested this solution and messed around with it to fit my exact problem and works nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = { 'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'ID': [1, 2, 2, 3], 'B': [0, 0, 'a', 0], 'C': [0, 0, 'a', 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index += 1
index_to_be_replaced = 2
index_to_use_to_replace = 3
columns_to_replace = ['ID', 'B', 'C']
columns_not_to_replace = ['A']

x = df[columns_not_to_replace].loc[index_to_be_replaced]
y = df[columns_to_replace].loc[index_to_use_to_replace]
df.loc[index_to_be_replaced] = pd.concat([x, y]) 
print(df)
```

Does it solve your problem? I would check on other pandas functions, as well. Like join, merge.

```
❯ python3 b.py
   A  ID  B  C
1  a   1  0  0
2  b   2  a  a
3  c   2  a  a
4  d   3  0  0
```

Comment: One part of the problem is seemingly solved by this, for which, thanks. The other half of the problem is how to identify the row indexes that needs changing, i can't do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
s = df.loc[df[["B","C"]].ne("0").all(1)].set_index("ID")[["B", "C"]]

print (s.combine_first(df.set_index("ID")).reset_index())

   ID  A  B  C  Index
0   1  a  0  0    1.0
1   2  b  a  a    2.0
2   2  c  a  a    3.0
3   3  d  0  0    4.0
```